# Ruby - English sentence-like list from an array of words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Ruby/Rails "magic" helper to go from an array of words, like

```
["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"]
```

to a single string which can fit in a sentence:

```
"Sugar, Water, Lemons and Tea"
```

I know about `array.join()`, but the "and" before the last entry is important.
I am just asking because I know Ruby and Rails have a lot of helpful methods lurking in the dark and I want to keep my code as clean as possible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like this is what you're looking for :)

http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence

`to_sentence(options = {})`

"Converts the array to a comma-separated sentence where the last element is joined by the connector word."

Example:

`["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"].to_sentence # => "Sugar, Water, Lemons, and Tea"`

You can also pass options, like what should be your last word connector:

`["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"].to_sentence(last_word_connector: ' or ') # => "Sugar, Water, Lemons or Tea"`

EDIT:

As pointed out by Max Williams, this will by default leave a comma next to the last word. To avoid that, you can explicitly declare `" and "` as your last word connector, as the default seems to be `", and "`

`["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"].to_sentence(last_word_connector: ' and ') # => "Sugar, Water, Lemons and Tea"`

Comment: That puts an extra comma before the "and" so isn't quite what he asked for.  This is the infamous "oxford comma", which Vampire Weekend don't give a f*ck about. :)

Comment: See what I mean! Ruby is just loaded with mysterious methods like these. Thanks @rorofromfrance

Comment: Ah, nice edit, didn't know about the connector option.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
pry(main)> ["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"].to_sentence
=> "Sugar, Water, Lemons, and Tea"
```

or

```
 pry(main)> ["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"].to_sentence(words_connector: ', ', last_word_connector: ' and ')
  => "Sugar, Water, Lemons and Tea"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use join, just do the last element separately.

```
def commas_with_and(arr)
  arr[0..-2].join(", ") << " and " << arr[-1]
end

arr = ["Sugar", "Water", "Lemons", "Tea"]
commas_with_and(arr)
>>  "Sugar, Water, Lemons and Tea"
```